# ViewPager with swipe out functionality

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I tried to implement custom ViewPager with functionality that you can swipe out the fragment on both sides and the top fragment will be removed from pager adapter (something like STACK). e.g there are 5 fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter. I use custom PageTransformer with stack effect that the first fragment covers the second and the second covers the third etc. When I swipe out the first (TOP) fragment (no matter what side - swipe out to left and swipe out to right take the same effect - remove the top fragment). 
Do you know implementation of ViewPager like this? I tried to understand the code of ViewPager but it has to many lines of code and it is really difficult to understand it. It's black magic to me. I will be very helpful is somebody help me with my problem. Or give me some hints how to implement custom ViewPager with desired functionality.

On this video is displayed very similar functionality:
http://youtu.be/533awlmpXr4?list=UUGOLwlIxP5GX-2Rhx_TXwFg

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a gesture detector and assign it to your pager:

```
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureDetector());
mPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{           
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

This detects left and right swipe. When you have detected this you can remove your current view from the pager or change the order or ....

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY)
    {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
                    Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // left
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
                    Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // right
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not working. My ViewPager doesn't handle onTouch event. I tried to Log that. But onTouch event is never called for some reason (I don't know why).

Comment: We are talking about the ViewPager from the appcompat so android.support.v4.view.ViewPager ? Then your touch events are captured somewhere else because that definitely works. I have a very similar setup in my app.